# AWK: Is there a way to limit the width of an output field?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk, nawk

I need to limit the final size of a field to 2048. I could probably use:

```
ACTION_PARAMETER=substr($2,1,2048);
```

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use printf

```
printf "%.2048s\n", $2
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Since there haven't been any red flags brought up with my substr($2, 1, 2048), I'm going to stick with that for now. I am using a simple "print a, b, c, d" that is very long and I'd rather not restructure it with a printf if i don't need to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate way:

```
printf "%.2048s", $2
```

Comment: Please see my comment to user000001. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the field separator `FS` being `""` and then limiting the number of fields `NF`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} NF=2048' file
```

#### Example with 3 instead of 2048

```
$ cat a
hello
how are
you
i am ok

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} NF=3' a
hel
how
you
i a
```

or even as a parameter:

```
$ awk -v limit=2 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} NF=limit' a
he
ho
yo
i
```

Comment: I won't be able to use this trick. It's clever I'll grant that. In my case I have two audit log files I am processing with many fields of all different types and sizes.

Comment: OK! If you need to use `FS` and `NF` in other parts, then my approach won't help, sure.

Answer (score 1):

How about native bash parameter slicing

```
printf "%s" ${2:0:2048}
```